# Javascript get year month date and time in custom format

Tags: javascript, date

In Javascript I want to get the current data and time in a custom format like this. `"2016-01-01T05:06:07"`. Can someone tell me how to get the current year-month-date-time in this format with quickest solution?
As you can see I have trailing zeros with month, dates, hours, minutes and seconds so I want exactly like that. 
Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the *toISOString* method? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The *toISOString* method provides the format you wish, but since it uses UTC you'll need to adjust the time for the local offset and trim the ends to remove the time zone and decimal seconds:

```js
function toLocalISOString(date) {
  var d = new Date(+date);
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset());
  return d.toISOString().replace(/(\.\d+)|(z$)/gi,'');
}

document.write(toLocalISOString(new Date()));
```

It could be added as a method to *Date.prototype*. I don't know how it will go over daylight saving boundaries, you should test thoroughly.

A polyfill for [*toISOString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#Polyfill) is available on MDN if required.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [ISO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
var date = (new Date()).toISOString();
document.write('<pre>' + date + '</pre>');
date = date.substring(0, 19);
document.write('<pre>' + date + '</pre>');
```

The Z is for the timezone, you can remove it by substring, like the fractions of seconds just before the Z.

Comment: thanks, but its showing time without time zone adding. Means its showing like `2015-12-09T03:25:49` but it should show time like `2015-12-09T08:55:49` by adding timezone

Comment: I'm in a hurry so can't post code but you can take the polyfill in the mozilla link and change all `getUTC...` by the simple `get...` (ex: `getUTCTime()` -> `getTime()`). You'll have the datetime in locale timezone.